# Displaying one directive with multiple view options in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two modules wrapped inside of directives called 'bci-directive' and 'bcd-directive' that I use to display data inside of a primary module called 'core'. I am trying to give users a way to view these two modules in two different ways, one where they can view both at the same time, and one where they can see each separated by tabs -- the issue I am running into is that each of these directives has isolated scope so each pair of tags generates a new view which results in incorrect behavior in updating controller variables within the two sub-modules when users make edits. What I would like is to be able to a single view for each of these modules that can switch between the two view options(tab/all) while maintaining the same scope.

So far I've tried moving these views out of directives and into ng-includes with the same results, I wasn't able to find much more for suggestions while researching.  Here is what I currently have for the front end:

```
<div ng-cloak="">
<md-toolbar class="md-primary">
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <!-- span tag to align buttons to right -->
        <span flex=""></span>
        <md-button ng-click="core.initiateSave()" class="md-raised">SAVE ALL</md-button>
        <md-checkbox ng-model="core.tabView" aria-label="tabViewSwitch" class="md-warn">
            Tab View
        </md-checkbox>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>
<div ng-show="core.tabView">
    <md-content>
        <md-tabs md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="" class="md-primary md-hue-2">
            <md-tab label="Details">
                <bcd-directive></bcd-directive>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab label="Items">
                <bci-directive></bci-directive>
            </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
    </md-content>
</div>
<!-- View All: These are new views with new controllers that use same factory as above directives -->
<div ng-show="!core.tabView">
    <bcd-directive></bcd-directive>
    <bci-directive></bci-directive>
</div>
<div style="position:fixed;top:50%;left:50%">
    <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" class="md-warn loader" md-diameter="60" ng-hide="!loading" ng-disabled="!loading"></md-progress-circular>
</div>
```

And the directives:

```
(function(){
'use strict';
angular
.module('app.bci')
.directive('bciDirective', bciDirective);

/* @ngInject */
function bciDirective(){
    var directive = {
        templateUrl: '../app/sf/bci/templates/bci.html',
        controller: 'bciController',
        controllerAs: 'bci',
        scope: {},
        bindToController: true,
        restrict: 'E'
    };
    return directive;
 }
})();
```

Is it possible to switch between these view options without having to instantiate the directives twice?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `template` property of your directive definition object to a function that will return your dynamic template:

```
restrict: "E",
replace: true,
template: function(tElement, attributes) {
    return getTemplate(attributes.template);
}
```

And then assign that from the parent based on your condition where you can access the attributes through `attributes`.

Now your template is being determined before the compile phase, and you don't need to manually compile it.